# HttpPost executes async .FromSqlRaw multiple times even though it is called only once in the web app

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor

I have a .NET 5/aspnetcore/blazor server web app, and the front/back ends of the app communicate through an API layer within the app.

When I call the API in the front end, the call is issued only once (I have verified this), but within the HttpPost Task, the dbContext gets queried multiple times (4 times per API call, in my case). Not sure why this is happening, and would appreciate any sort of insight from the community.

**this is my .razor file. If I put a breakpoint on the async API request, it only executes one time.**

```
private async Task FetchData()
{
    var result = await Client.GetData(_page, _pageSize);
}
```

**this is my data access code. If I put a breakpoint on `var response = await _dbContext.Data.FromSqlRaw`, it gets hit 4 times.**

```
[HttpPost("/Api/Data/GetData")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetData([FromQuery] int currentPage, [FromQuery] int currentPageSize)
{
    PagedResponse<List<DataDto>> pagedData = new PagedResponse<List<DataDto>>(new List<DataDto>(), currentPage, currentPageSize);

    var route = Request.Path.Value;
    var filterOut = new PaginationFilter(currentPage, currentPageSize, null, null);
    int countResult = 0;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //get paginated set
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    try
    {
        SqlParameter[] parameters =
        {
                new SqlParameter
                {
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                    ParameterName = "pageNumber",
                    Value = currentPage
                },
                new SqlParameter
                {
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                    ParameterName = "pageSize",
                    Value = currentPageSize
                },
                new SqlParameter
                {
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
                    ParameterName = "countResult",
                    Value = countResult
                }
            };

        var response = await _dbContext.Data.FromSqlRaw("Execute dbo.sp_GetDataForFilter @pageNumber, @pageSize, @countResult OUTPUT", parameters).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        countResult = (int)parameters.Where(x => x.ParameterName == "countResult").FirstOrDefault().Value;

        List<DataDto> responseDto = new List<DataDto>();
        foreach (var item in response)
        {
            responseDto.Add(new DataDto(item));
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //build pagedReponse
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        pagedData = PaginationHelper.CreatePagedReponse(responseDto, filterOut, countResult, _uriService, route);
        return Ok(pagedData);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Handle error
    }
}
```

**edits (per Henk)---------**

here is my `AuthorizationMessageHandler`

```
class AuthorizationMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly AppStateService _appState;
    private readonly ILogger<AuthorizationMessageHandler> _logger;

    public AuthorizationMessageHandler(
        AppStateService appState,
        ILogger<AuthorizationMessageHandler> logger)
    {
        _appState = appState;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage;
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_appState?.AuthenticationCookie) == false)
            {
                request.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.Cookie, _appState.AuthenticationCookie);
            }

            httpResponseMessage = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to run http query {RequestUri}", request.RequestUri);
            throw;
        }

        return httpResponseMessage;
    }
}
```

and here is where I initialize Http in my `Startup.cs`

```
private static void InitializeHttp(IServiceCollection services, ServiceConfiguration serviceConfiguration)
{
    services.AddTransient<AuthorizationMessageHandler>();

    AsyncRetryPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> retryPolicy = HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(serviceConfiguration.Http.Retry, _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(serviceConfiguration.Http.Wait));

    AsyncTimeoutPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(serviceConfiguration.Http.Timeout));

    // Discover all IApiClient implementations and configure a Refit http client for each.
    var apiClientInterfaceType = typeof(IApiClient);
    var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
        .Where(t => apiClientInterfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.IsInterface);

    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        // We have to do this nonsense, because there is a bug in AddRefitClient (non-generic version)
        // where it does not properly register the client.
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Refit.HttpClientFactoryExtensions).GetMethods()
            .FirstOrDefault(m =>
                m.Name.Equals(nameof(Refit.HttpClientFactoryExtensions.AddRefitClient), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                m.IsGenericMethod);
        MethodInfo generic = method?.MakeGenericMethod(type);

        IHttpClientBuilder builder = (IHttpClientBuilder)generic?.Invoke(null, new object[] { services, null });

        builder.ConfigureHttpClient(c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri(serviceConfiguration.Application.BaseUrl))
            .AddPolicyHandler(retryPolicy)
            .AddPolicyHandler(timeoutPolicy)
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthorizationMessageHandler>();
    }
}
```

Comment: The calls are made by  the Client, post that part.

Comment: What calls `FetchData`?  It's possible it's getting called so early in the lifecycle that the debugger hasn't yet attached, which could explain the disconnect between number of times the breakpoint fires between the server and client.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I made an edit. Please let me know if I didn't give you what you were seeking.

Comment: @KirkWoll `FetchData` is called in my `OnAfterRenderAsync` --> `if(firstrender)` block of the .razor lifecycle.

Comment: another weird thing I noticed is that when i'm running the app locally in debug mode, the stored procedure is getting executed only once per API call (I am logging to a table within SQL Sever within the stored proc), but when I am running the app in prod, (azure) the stored procedure is getting executed more than once. Now the proc seems to be executing 2-3 times per API call in prod. It seems that it executes more often when the server is inactive (lots of time passes between http requests), but as I refresh the page, the proc executes around twice per API call.

Comment: The culprit, in my case, was the Polly `AsyncRetryPolicy` in my `Startup.cs` file. If the http response didn't come within the timeout window (2 seconds in my implementation) it would retry the httprequest. I extended the timeout window to 100 seconds (do you think this is a reasonable window?) and I'm no longer seeing the retries (obviously).